# Detect text in image and trace on them

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I need some help with image processing , I'm working on a script which can detect Alphabets on the image and trace them , For example if there is a letter **A** in the Image then code has to detect it and trace(side-by-side not over same line) 3-4 times (with different colors) with given distance based on width of the text . As of now I'am able to detect the words  and font and size using **tesserocr** module, but I'm unable to do the tracing thing .

```js
import io
import tesserocr
from PIL import Image

with tesserocr.PyTessBaseAPI() as api:
    image = Image.open("1d.png")
    api.SetImage(image)
    api.Recognize() 
    iterator = api.GetIterator()
    print iterator.WordFontAttributes()
```

Thanks in advance #peace